# dispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:) crash when UIViewController dismissed swift

Tags: ios, swift

When i press a button, a modal UIViewController appears with a slideshow of UIImageViews in a UIScrollView. I am doing this to change to the next item every 3 seconds:

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 3
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
    scrollView.scrollToViewAtIndex(nextItem(), animated: true)
}
```

The only problem is that, when i dismiss this UIViewController, the code will be waiting the delay, and then crash.

[image: This is the only error i can see]

How can i solve this ?
Thanks

Comment: @ Farid :- Can you share the crash log

Comment: You are accessing nil of scrollView. You dismissed the controller, the controller destroy its all objects, then scrollView is in not memory.

Comment: If you share the log, we can help you better. My guess is it is because you are holding a strong reference to `self` in the execution block. You might want to use `[weak self]` instead and see what happens.

Comment: @Coder the problem is that there is no crash log ..

Comment: @OzgurVatansever What do you mean by that ?

Comment: @JaleelNazir i think so but i don't know how to solve it

Comment: @ Farid :- Try using a NSTimer and when you dismiss the viewcontroller set timer to nil

Comment: use Delegate between two controller, Update bottom controller to scroll to Index by delegate and then  dismiss Top viewcontroller

Comment: @Coder Setting timer to `nil` does not stop the timer, you have to `invalidate` it.

Comment: @ Sulthan :- Sorry, my bad

Comment: @Coder i did this, working thank you

Comment: It's possible this could be fixed just by checking `scrollView.window != nil` before trying to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You are retaining a strong reference to the scrollView.  If you do this it should only hold a weak link and therefore when the owning view controller is destroyed it won't cause an error:

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 3
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) { [weak self] in
    self?.scrollView.scrollToViewAtIndex(nextItem(), animated: true)
}
```

Of course you could also switch to using a Timer but that is another story.